# клонирование веток удаленного репозитория

Tags: git, git-clone

Как клонировать удаленный репозиторий одновременно со всеми ветками?

Так понял, что

```
git clone remote_rep
```

клонирует только мастер ветку, а потом для клонирования веток

```
git clone remote_rep -b branch_name
```

Как это сделать в один шаг?

Comment: когда ты склонировал весь репозиторий, то можешь переключаться между существующими ветками командой git checkout <name-branch>

Comment: когда я склонировал удаленный  репозиторий он имел мастер ветку и еще одну,  в клонированном же я вначале вижу только мастер ветку через git branch

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3099621/2513573

Answer (score 10, accepted):

по умолчанию клонируются все объекты (*commit*, *tree*, *blob*) и все указатели (*branch*, *tag*).

а так как ветка (*branch*) в *git* — это всего лишь плавающий указатель на *commit*, то все такие указатели в вашем локальном репозитории (который находится в каталоге `.git`) — уже есть.

но их «не видно» при выполнении команды `git branch` (зато видно при выполнении команды `git branch -a`).

---

склонировать репозиторий «в один шаг», так, чтобы их сразу «было видно», увы, нельзя.

вот [тут, например, рекомендуют](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3099621/2513573) после клонирования выполнять небольшую программу на языке оболочки:

```
$ for remote in `git branch -r | grep -v /HEAD`; do git checkout --track $remote ; done
```

---

предлагаю опробовать моё оригинальное решение без использования программы на языке оболочки (выполнять надо в пустом каталоге):

```
$ git clone --bare url-репозитория .git
$ git config core.bare false
$ git checkout
```

после этого вы сразу должны увидеть в выводе команды `git branch` все ветки, что присутствуют и в удалённом репозитории.

---

[копия](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37346281/4827341) существенной части ответа на stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Решение действительно оригинальное!

Comment: @NickVolynkin, у вас на *apple/osx* срабатывает? я проверил на нескольких версиях *git* — минимальной 1.5.4.3, максимальной 2.1.4. везде сработало.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно клонировать удаленный репозиторий со всеми ветками нужно после:

```
git clone PATH
```

сделать:

```
git checkout [имя_другого_НЕ_мастер_бранча]
```

и локальная ветка соответствующая удалённой будет создана. Сами объекты (коммиты) склонированы, просто ветки не созданы.