# скачать все ветки репозитория с github из командной строки

Tags: git, github, git-bash

Подскажите пожалуйста, как скачать все ветки с одного удаленного репозитория GitHub на локальную машину из командной строки git?

Команда

```
git pull origin master
```

Скачивает только одну ветку.

Вопрос заключается в следующем: Как скачать репозиторий полностью со всеми ветками находящимися в данном репозитории с папками, вложенными папками и файлами  на локальную машину из командной строки git?

Уточнение: Из командной строки git на системе Windows. Из терминала git в системе Windows. (git-bash)

---

PS. Как длинно вопрос стал звучать.

Comment: [How to fetch all Git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312521)

Comment: Скачиваются всегда все ветки (если специально не постараться), так что вопрос неяснен

Comment: [How to clone all remote branches in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699)

Comment: @AlexeyTen Нет, конечно же.

Comment: может, речь об [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/525610/178576)?

Comment: А точно. Перепутал с pull без указания ветки.

Answer (score 2):

получить актуальное состояние удаленного git-репозитория (в т.ч. из github) можно командой

```
git fetch
```

после успешного выполнения команды вам будут доступны удаленные ветки в их актуальном состоянии. Затем можно перейти к текущей версии удаленной ветки, например master, командой

```
git checkout origin/master
```