# В чём смысл, что git clone отображает локальной только одну ветку main?

Tags: git

В чём суть и логика подхода, то что при git clone локальной отображается только ветка main?
Ведь все файлы для всех веток копируются из удалённого репозитория только один раз при клонировании, почему бы все ветки не отображать сразу как локальные?
А сейчас нужно сначала их посмотреть:

```
git branch -a
```

А затем создать:

```
git branch feature/branch_1
```

Зачем так сделали?

Comment: можно сделать fetch и сделать checkout  и ничего создавать не надо.....

Comment: А сделали возможно для того, чтобы как минимум твоя локальная история была чистая....вот работа ведётся 100 разработчиками и на сервере 12367547 веток.... зачем они все тебе на твоём компе?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, что такое локальная история? Вроде история не делится на локальную и удалённую?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/525610/178576

Comment: @Qwertiy да имелся в виду список локальный)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, список веток?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, ой, это не тебе вопрос был...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, тебе)

Comment: @Qwertiy да...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, ты работаешь с несколькими ветками, а 90+% существующих веток других разработчиков тебе никогда не понадобятся - так зачем захламлять ими список локальных веток?

Во-вторых, ветки могут обновляться. Если сразу создать всем веткам локальные аналоги, то когда тебе понадобится ветка, она окажется неактуальна, из-за чего придётся делать pull или fetch.

Ну и если вдруг пришло в голову автоматически обновлять локальные ветки, то разработчик вполне может хотеть иметь ветку на конкретном комите. А ещё есть удаление веток, а я могу не хотеть, чтобы некоторую локальную ветку удалили.